# xwiki takes 100 cpu

Tags: tomcat, cpu, wiki, xwiki

I have installed Xwiki 4.4.
If I visit a page on my wiki, the cpu load goes up to 100%.
The load goes down as soon as the page has finished loading.

I have done a few steps described on: http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Performances

Where is the problem?

Here is a picture of htop:
http://d60.img-up.net/xwiki_htop3fef.png

My server is virtualized ans has 2 GB RAM.

Tomcat Log:

```
Wrapped Exception: Java heap space
com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 0 in 11: Uncaught exception
Wrapped Exception: Java heap space
        at com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:254) [xwiki-platform-legacy-oldcore-4.4.jar:na]
        at com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:116) [xwiki-platform-legacy-oldcore-4.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [struts-1.2.9.jar:1.2.9]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) [servlet-api-2.5.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) [servlet-api-2.5.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:120) [xwiki-platform-legacy-oldcore-4.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:144) [xwiki-platform-wysiwyg-server-4.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at com.xpn.xwiki.plugin.webdav.XWikiDavFilter.doFilter(XWikiDavFilter.java:66) [xwiki-platform-webdav-server-4.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208) [xwiki-platform-container-servlet-4.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111) [xwiki-platform-container-servlet-4.4.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote-6.0.35.jar:6.0.35]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [na:1.6.0_18]
```

Tomcat (Catalina Log?)

```
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [Job Manager daemon thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [Lucene Index Updater] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@126f0939]) and a value of type [org.python.core.ThreadState] (value [org.python.core.ThreadState@37c686a3]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@4ab153f0]) and a value of type [org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm] (value [ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1] (value [com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1@3267924b]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@2db593c7]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector$1] (value [org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector$1@6bf90542]) and a value of type [boolean[]] (value [[Z@29c8676f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1] (value [com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1@3267924b]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@23febdd7]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:09 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3fe51ea2]) and a value of type [org.infinispan.context.SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext] (value [SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext{flags=null}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2737 ms
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
Jan 15, 2013 1:18:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor xwiki.xml
Jan 15, 2013 1:19:07 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:19:07 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 25366 ms
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Reloading context [/xwiki]
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [Job Manager daemon thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [Lucene Index Updater] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [Statistics storing daemon] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@29c51b4e]) and a value of type [org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm] (value [ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1] (value [com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1@3370ec9d]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@3abe51cd]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector$1] (value [org.sonatype.guice.bean.inject.BeanInjector$1@24ec87dc]) and a value of type [boolean[]] (value [[Z@24cb8f74]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@30371b8b]) and a value of type [org.infinispan.context.SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext] (value [SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext{flags=null}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@71f15b67]) and a value of type [org.infinispan.context.SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext] (value [SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext{flags=null}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@1ca801a2]) and a value of type [org.infinispan.context.SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext] (value [SingleKeyNonTxInvocationContext{flags=null}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.xpn.xwiki.store.migration.AbstractDataMigrationManager.ThreadLock] (value [com.xpn.xwiki.store.migration.AbstractDataMigrationManager$ThreadLock@64827e06]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:58 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.xpn.xwiki.store.migration.AbstractDataMigrationManager.ThreadLock] (value [com.xpn.xwiki.store.migration.AbstractDataMigrationManager$ThreadLock@64827e06]) and a value of type [java.lang.Integer] (value [0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:26:59 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/xwiki] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/xwiki] appears to have started a thread named [Job Manager daemon thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:16 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat6/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:19 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1319 ms
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor xwiki.xml
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:38 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jan 15, 2013 1:27:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 18762 ms
Jan 15, 2013 1:42:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters
INFO: Invalid chunk starting at byte [0] and ending at byte [0] with a value of [null] ignored
```

Comment: You should post some more informations, like your websever logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you left Tomcat with the default memory settings. XWiki is quite resource intensive, so at least 512M of heap space and 128M of PermGen space is required for good stability, double that for good performance.

The stack trace itself suggests this is happening:

> Wrapped Exception: Java heap space

The JVM takes up a lot of CPU because it continuously tries to free more memory by running the garbage collector.

See [XWiki's Tomcat Installation Guide](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/InstallationTomcat#HOutOfMemoryError) for more details, and how to fix it.

Comment: Ah okay. I can't find the config file of tomcat in  `/etc/tomcatX/tomcatX.conf or /etc/conf.d/tomcatX.conf`
I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat6.config`

Comment: My config file:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m"`
But the cpu load is still at 100%

Comment: My wiki is loading a bit faster, but the load still goes to 90% while the site is loading.

Comment: I have it! :D
There are many configuration files for tomcat6..
`/etc/init.d/tomcat6` and `/etc/default/tomcat6` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/tomcat6.config` CPU load goes to 20% while loading a site. Thats ok :)

Comment: It'd be nice if the packaged versions (e.g. for ubuntu) set these values to something reasonable during install.